# Variable becomes 0 when accessing from within Object

Tags: javascript

I have created an Object like so:

```
var Object = function() {
    var value = 0;

    function do() {
        console.log(value);
    }

    return {
        do : do,
        value : value
    }
};
exports.Object = Object;
```

I am calling the `do` function from outside of this Object:

```
function call(object) {
    console.log(object.value);
    object.update();
}
```

I have set the value to equal 2.5 outside of the player class. The bizarre thing is that when I execute the code, the console logs this:

```
2.5
0
2.5
0
```

So it seems that the value is 0 from within the class, but 2.5 when I access it from outside it. What is the issue here?

My background is mainly Java, and I am rather new to Javascript, so perhaps I have missed something trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Josh mentioned, this is a `value` vs `reference` issue, which is usually addressed by either returning an object (so it's by reference) or including functions like `getValue` and `setValue`.

For the second option, you could actually re-write your function and use `getters`, like so:

```
var Object = function() {
    var value = 0;

    function _do() {
        console.log(value);
    }
    function update(val) {
        value = val * .5;
    }
    return {
        do: _do,
        update: update,

        // Our fancy getter!
        get value() {
            return value;
        }
    }
};
exports.Object = Object;
```

At this point, `Object.value` would behave similar to `getValue`.

Since it's Friday, let's go crazy and add our `setter` as well:

```
var Object = function() {
    var value = 0;

    function _do() {
        console.log(value);
    }
    return {
        do: _do,

        // Our fancy getters/setters!
        get value() {
            return value;
        },
        set value(val) {
            value = val * .5;
        }
    }
};
exports.Object = Object;
```

Then you're doing things like:

```
Object.value; // Returns 0
Object.value = 5;
Object.value; // Returns 2.5
Object.do(); // Logs 2.5
```

[Defining Getters and Setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

[Getter/Setter compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Getter_in_property_initializer)

Comment: This is much cleaner. Thank you for the detailed explanation. Its Saturday morning here. So a bit too crazy ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have created a closure: You're returning an object which has a property `value`, but the `var value` inside the closure *does not change* when you change the `value` property of the returned object.

Explained another way, when you say `new Object`, then you get two `value`s one is returned as a property of the object, and the other is the `var object` hidden inside the closure.

Try the following:

```
var Object = function() {
    this.value = 0;

    function do() {
        console.log(this.value);
    }

    return {
        do : do
    }
};

exports.Object = new Object;
```

Alternatively:

```
var Object = function() {
    var value = 0;

    function do() {
        console.log(value);
    }

    return {
        do : do,
        getValue : function(){ return value; },
        setValue : function(val){ value = val; }
    }
};

exports.Object = Object;
```

Comment: If I don't return the value, doesn't that mean it's not accessible?

Comment: If you make a `var` then that value is "local" to the closure, and you can only modify it within the closure. If you use `this.value` then the property is "public" and accessible

Comment: The first solution gives me an error: value is not defined when I try to log it.

Comment: Whoops, fixed, `this.value`

Comment: Ok now when I log the value, it is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, you needed to use `new`. I recommend reading a primer on JavaScript classes

Answer (score 0):

In fact , your code is equivalent to

```
var Object = function() {
  var value = 0;

  function do() {
    console.log(value);
  }

  var res= {
    do : do,
    value : value
  }
  return res;
 };
exports.Object = Object;
```

the function `do()` will not log the `res.value`. Instead it logs a local variable of function `Object`, that means you can't change the value `do` returns.

if you want to log `res.value`, can try following:

```
function do(){
    console.log(this.value);
}
```

However I have to mention something else.
if `value` is an object instead of literal. you can easily access it. A closure is unable to protect an object from been changed as object is passed by ref.

Just try this:

```
var Object = function() {
    var value = [0];

    function doSth() {
        console.log(value[0]);
    }

    var res= {
        do : doSth,
        value : value
    }
    return res;
};
exports.Object = Object;
```